# Oracle 12c REF CURSOR error

Tags: c++, oracle-12c

tengo un codigo en c++ que funciona correctamente en la comunicación con Oracle 11g, hace poco actualizamos a Oracle 12c release2 y desde entonces ya no funciona el codigo generando el error en execute:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_CON_UNIDAD'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

este es el codigo en c++:

```
ADD_COMMAND_EX(pConnection, pCommand, Registro,adCmdStoredProc)
ADD_PARAMETER(pCommand, 0, adInteger, adParamInput, sizeof(int),vtDefTypeID)
ADD_PARAMETER(pCommand, 1, adBigInt, adParamInput, sizeof(int),vtDefID)
ADD_PARAMETER(pCommand, 2, adVarChar, adParamOutput, 80,vtMissing)
ptrRecordSet = pCommand->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdStoredProc | adCmdUnspecified);
```

y mi codigo en Oracle no ha cambiado:

```
TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;
procedure SP_CON_UNIDAD(i_n_DefTypeID IN NUMBER,
                      i_n_DefID IN NUMBER,
                      o_v2MnsjeError OUT VARCHAR2,
                      crRefCursor2 OUT cur_type);
```

Agradezco cualquier colaboración, por que es confuso que solo con actualizar la versión de Oracle se genere este error.

Comment: Lo que me parece extraño es que tu _SP_ se llama `SP_CON_UNIDAD`, pero el mensaje de error hace mención a una llamada a `UNIDAD`, sin `SP_CON_`. Sospecho que estás llamando al SP incorrecto.

Comment: Tienes razón, lo había borrado la _SP_ es `SP_CON_UNIDAD `, igual el error persiste